# GeoServer 2.10.1 Center Justify Polygon Label Style File .xml

Tags: geoserver, labeling, sld, center

The Title kind of says it all.  Trying to Center Justify a label of a polygon using a sld style file on Geoserver 2.10.1.  Here is the code snippet followed by a screenshot of the label now.

```
          <sld:Rule>
        <ogc:Filter>
          <ogc:PropertyIsLike wildCard="*" singleChar="#" escapeChar="!">
            <ogc:PropertyName>building</ogc:PropertyName>
            <ogc:Literal>*</ogc:Literal>
          </ogc:PropertyIsLike>
        </ogc:Filter>
        <sld:MinScaleDenominator>0</sld:MinScaleDenominator>
        <sld:MaxScaleDenominator>3600</sld:MaxScaleDenominator>
        <sld:Name>Yes</sld:Name>
        <sld:Title>Building</sld:Title>
        <sld:PolygonSymbolizer>
          <sld:Fill>
            <sld:CssParameter name="fill">#d4d6e4</sld:CssParameter>
          </sld:Fill>
          <sld:Stroke>
            <sld:CssParameter name="stroke">#d4d6e4</sld:CssParameter>
            <sld:CssParameter name="stroke-width">0.5</sld:CssParameter>
            <sld:CssParameter name="stroke-linejoin">round</sld:CssParameter>
          </sld:Stroke>
        </sld:PolygonSymbolizer>
        <sld:TextSymbolizer>
          <sld:Label>
            <ogc:PropertyName>name</ogc:PropertyName>
          </sld:Label>
          <sld:Font>
            <sld:CssParameter name="font-size">12</sld:CssParameter>
            <sld:CssParameter name="font-family">Nimbus Sans L Regular Condensed</sld:CssParameter>
          </sld:Font>
          <sld:LabelPlacement>
            <sld:LinePlacement>
              <sld:PerpendicularOffset>0</sld:PerpendicularOffset>
            </sld:LinePlacement>
          </sld:LabelPlacement>
          <sld:Fill>
            <sld:CssParameter name="fill">#749dae</sld:CssParameter>
          </sld:Fill>
          <sld:VendorOption name="maxDisplacement">50</sld:VendorOption>
          <sld:VendorOption name="labelAllGroup">TRUE</sld:VendorOption>
          <sld:VendorOption name="removeOverlaps">TRUE</sld:VendorOption>
          <sld:VendorOption name="autoWrap">40</sld:VendorOption>
          <sld:VendorOption name="group">TRUE</sld:VendorOption>
          <sld:Halo>
            <sld:Radius>
              <ogc:Literal>0.26</ogc:Literal>
            </sld:Radius>
            <sld:Fill>
              <sld:CssParameter name="fill">#bce6f4</sld:CssParameter>
            </sld:Fill>
          </sld:Halo>
        </sld:TextSymbolizer>
      </sld:Rule>
```

[image: Screen shot]

Answer (score 1):

I don't beleive this is currently possible. You (or someone else) could [write a function](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/tutorial/function.html) that centred some text by padding with spaces but there is little chance it would ever get backported as far back as 2.10 which is several years obselete.